# executing php code onto another server needs <?php

Tags: windows, php, execution

I have copied some code from one Linux server to my windows machine.
When i execute it i have to put `<?php` instead of `<?` for the code to run ???
 is there any way to change this in wondows ?

Comment: If this is your code, then for the best level of compatibility you suggest that you should avoid using short open tags.  It is disabled  in many places.  It can be problematic if you have XML files stored or used anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435705/why-is-no-longer-working-and-instead-only-php-works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `short_open_tag` directive in your php.ini file to `On` and restart your web server.

As Zoredache pointed out, for greatest compatibility you should always use `<?php` tags in your own code, and lobby developers who use short tags to do it properly and stop being lazy.

Comment: agreed but it's quite old code and modifying would take some time :)) 10x for the heads up